# No variants found for `react-native-reanimated`

Tags: react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, react-native-reanimated

I upgraded my React Native project to Gradle 7.0.2 and now when I open Android Studio it says `No variants found for ':react-native-reanimated'`. I'm using `react-native-reanimated@1.13.3`, and from the [documentation](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/1.x.x/getting_started) for versions 1.x.x there's no real configuration, so I'm not sure how to approach this.
Has anyone run into anything similar? I'm using `react-native@0.63.4`, gradle 7.0.2, and Android Gradle Plugin 7.0.0.

Comment: I faced the same situation, mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70726037/react-native-reanimated-compilesdkversion-is-not-specified/70862139#70862139

Comment: @ridvanaltun Is changing the `distributionUrl` line all you had to do in order to downgrade the gradle version?

Comment: @ridvanaltun When I make that change, it throws the error `Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'. Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.0.2. Current version is 6.8.1`

Comment: If you build your project with `react-native run-android` command, yes, replacing Gradle version in gradle-wapper.properties file works. I don't know why Android Studio can't handle this

Comment: @ridvanaltun Which version of Android Studio are you using? I have the one from Jan 2021, and it seems like I can't use the older version of Gradle with it. I might downgrade my Android Studio.

Comment: @ridvanaltun I got it to work using your advice, plus some other Android Studio downgrading. Feel free to post your answer as an actual response so I can accept.

Comment: i got same error in react native reanimated v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to downgrade your Gradle version 7 to 6 because somehow Gradle 7 not work with react-native-reanimated 1.13.3. You can downgrade the version from `gradle-wrapper.properties` file like below:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.1-all.zip
```

Comment: Confirming that this worked. In my case, I have to downgrade my entire Android Studio, because the version (2021.1) of Android Studio that I was running didn't support Gradle 6.8